# Как заставить цикл ждать событие?

Tags: javascript

Начал учить JS и возникло желание написать небольшую игру, по типу "показывается цифра в блоке и вам нужно ее ввести за определенное время". Так вот, не могу понять как заставить цикл for ждать пока я нажму определенную кнопку клавиатуры. Пробовал в этот цикл поместить while и в нем отслеживать нажатие кнопки, но страница все время грузится и не реагирует на нажатие:

```
while (temp!=0){
        $("body").keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 82) {
                checkInput(mas[full][round]);
                console.log("HP: " + health);
                if (health<=0) break;
                temp=0;
            }
        });
    }
```

Полный код (без моей тупой попытки):

```
var mas = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4]];
var health = 3;
for (var full = 0; full < mas.length; full++) {
    for(var round = 0; round < mas[full].length; round++) {
        //код для проверки нажатия
        //если кнопка нажата то мы сравниваем последнюю введеную цифру с текущей итерацией цикла (mas[full][round])
        checkInput(mas[full][round]);
        console.log("HP: " + health);
        if (health<=0) break;   
    }
    if (health<=0) break;   
}
function checkInput(skill) {
    console.log(skill);
    if (skill == 1) health++;
    if (skill != 1) health--;
    if (health>3) health=3;
    if (health<0) health=0;
    return skill, health;
}
```

Comment: Запускайте таймер на определенное время. Если пользователь успел напечатать до того, как таймер выстрелил, очищайте таймер. Если не успел - в событии таймера говорите - "Вы проиграли!".

Comment: @Igor походу я не правильно сформулировал вопрос, мне нужно, что бы итерация цикла состоялась только после того как я нажму клавишу на клавиатуре. Но спасибо, что что вы подсказали как раз следующее, что мне нужно было сделать

Comment: Если заставить цикл ждать, то страница не будет реагировать. Ваш подход в корне не верный. Лучше спросите какие другие варианты есть.

Comment: То что Вы описываете очень похоже на реактивное программирование, поэтому можете попробовать почитать о нём. Но на самом деле алгоритм с тайм-аутом, который истекает, более подходящий в данном случае.